# Crash battery power Ubuntu 12.04.5

Tags: 12.04, asus, battery, acpi, zram

My computer instantly turns off when trying to load ubuntu 12.04.5 on battery power. If I start with the ac plugged in then unplug the comp runs for hours, so the battery is fine. The crash happens when it gets to the lines shown in the picture.

[image]

I tried to remove zram with,

```
apt-get remove --purge zram-config
```

but that didn't change anything.

If I run grub with acpi=off i can start on battery power but then ubuntu freezes when trying to shutdown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using:
asus n53s,
Samsung SSD 850 EVO,
Ubuntu 12.04.5 lts,
Bio n53sv.209,
16gb ram,

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this one solved. After doing some digging I added nolapic to grub and everything seems to be working. I followed the process outline from this link
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2031780.html